# Why is "use namespace::autoclean" preferred to "no Moose"?

Tags: perl, moose

An often seen recommendation on best practices regarding `Moose` is the following:

> "The use `namespace::autoclean` bit is simply good code hygiene, as it removes imported symbols from your class's namespace at the end of your package's compile cycle, including `Moose` keywords. Once the class has been built, these keywords are not needed. **(This is preferred to placing `no Moose` at the end of your package)**."

Taken for [Moose::Manual::BestPractices](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Manual::BestPractices#namespace::autoclean_and_immutabilize) (emphasis mine).

I understand everything regarding the quote above, except for one thing: *why* is the use of `namespace::autoclean` preferred to the use of `no Moose` at the end of the lexical scope?

Is it just because `namespace::autoclean` is more versatile, allowing for more options in its use, or is there something intrinsic to the way it was implemented (specially tailored for `Moose` classes, perhaps) that makes it more reliable?

I found no documentation clarifying this, and I would much like to know the right answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`no Moose` gets rid of only those functions imported by `use Moose`.  `use namespace::autoclean` gets rid of all imported functions.

If you always use `namespace::autoclean`, then you don't have to remember to switch `no Moose` to `use namespace::autoclean` if you later come back and import a function from some module.  Otherwise, you might forget to do that.

Comment: `namespace::autoclean` will also break your code if you're planning on using overloads at the same time. For that case you may want to try out `namespace::sweep`.

Comment: Current `namespace::autoclean` (v0.28, Oct 2015) documentation [states](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559064/why-is-use-namespaceautoclean-preferred-to-no-moose) that "the magic subs installed by overload will not be cleaned".